# Invalid expression to be encrypted in SPAN AVISPA

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, encryption-symmetric

Can someone corrected me on what did i do wrong in line 15? It produced:

```
%% Syntax error: Line 15, Col 42 (offset 538-538, string ")")
%% Syn.Err(901): invalid expression to be encrypted
```

And the code for Line 15 is:

```
State = 1 /\ Rcv({Di'.Ei'.Fi',N'}_SKey2) =|> State' = 2 /\ Ci' = exp(IDi, Ai) /\ Bi' = xor(Di',Ci') 
/\ Ri' = new() /\ M1' =h(Bi'.Ri') /\ M2' = xor(h(Bi'), Ri') /\ Snd(M1'.M2'.Fi.IDj) /\ secret({PW1}, 
sec1, {Ui})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State = 1 /\ Rcv({Di'.Ei'.Fi',N'}_SKey2) =|> State' = 2 /\ Ci' = exp(IDi, Ai) /\ Bi' = xor(Di',Ci')
/\ Ri' := new() /\ M1' =h(Bi'.Ri') /\ M2' = xor(h(Bi'), Ri') /\ Snd(M1'.M2'.Fi.IDj) /\ secret({PW1}, sec1, {Ui})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, If you modify/define values on the right-hand side of =|> I think that you should replace '=' by ':='.

This should help (?)